# single class python list

Tags: python, overriding

How can every set method in python's list object be overridden in a derived object such that every item in that list is of a specific class?

Consider

```
class Index(int):
    pass


class IndexList(list):

    def __init__(self, int_list):
        for el in int_list:
            self.append(Index(el))

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        super(IndexList, self).__setitem__(key, Index(val))

    # override append insert etc...
```

Can this be done without directly overriding every single function that adds elements to the list?  I expected simply overriding `__setitem__` was enough.

Example, if `append` is not overridden.

```
ilist = IndexList([1,2])
ilist.append(3)

for i in ilist:
    print(isinstance(i, Index)) # True, True, False
```

Comment: I can't think of a good use case for this... Please, enlighten me ;)

Comment: I'm still debating whether my intention is good use.  The more I plan it the more I think it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to implement the various directly; the underlying C implementation does not call `__setitem__` for each and every change, as it is far more efficient to directly manipulate the (dynamically grown) C array.

Take a look at the [`collections` abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), specifically at the `MutableSequence` ABC, to get an idea of what methods all can mutate your list, to maintain your type invariant you'd need to implement `insert`, `append`, `extend` and `__iadd__`.

Better still, you can use the `collections.MutableSequence()` class as an alternative base class to `list`; this is a pure-python implementation that *does* cast many of those methods as calls to a core set of methods; you'd only need to provide implementations for `__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` and `insert`; any method named in the *Abstract Methods* column of the table.

```
class IndexList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, int_list):
        self._list = []
        for el in int_list:
            self.append(Index(el))

    def __len__(self): return len(self._list)
    def __getitem__(self, item): return self._list[item]
    def __delitem__(self, item): del self._list[item]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._list.key[index] = Index(value)

    def insert(self, index, value):
        self._list.insert(index, Index(value))
```